# why my application closed when i changed the lunch activity

Tags: android, android-activity

so when i changed the lunch activity from main activity to  acforpic the application keeps stoping and closing

```
 <activity
            android:name=".acforpic"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="ocr" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
```

Comment: If the application is stopping, you need to check the Logcat tab to see what the error message it gives you is. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) for some more details.

Answer (score 0):

That intent filter will launch the class at first time when app loads. .acforpic may be not an activity